# How to add network aliases in Linux for network computers

Tags: linux, networking, alias

In Windows, the c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file lets you add aliases to IPs so you can remember those computers with a familiar name.

Here's the header of the HOSTS file, for example 
=====================

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
```

=======================

What is the equivalent mechanism in Linux ? (RHEL 6.3, to be specific) ? What file do I need to modify/configure to get aliases for IPs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent is `/etc/hosts` and the format is the same:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
## '#' denote comments
## host IP       host alias
102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com
```

You can read about the `hosts` file in its manual page, accessible through `man hosts`.

Comment: The little diffrence is that you may add as many aliases as you want in Linux's `/etc/hosts`

Comment: @Kwaio And what makes you think you can't do that on Windows?

Comment: Oh well it's just not mentionned in the aforementionned commented lines